# Grouping SQL rows by time and user

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I currently have a problem with looping this query...

```
SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tdate) DIV 60) AS time, tid, date, tuser, SUM(tvalue) 
FROM transaction
WHERE tmerchant = '$fbid' 
GROUP BY tuser, EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM tdate)
ORDER BY tid DESC
LIMIT 40
```

The problem is that from this MySQL table:

```
10.20 AM - JOHN 10 
10.15 AM - GEORGE 10 
10.10 AM - GEORGE 10 
10.00 AM - JOHN 10
```

It will list:

```
10.10 AM - GEORGE 20 
10.00 AM - JOHN 20
```

And it should be the other way around, where the last row counts:

```
10.20 AM - JOHN 20 
10.15 AM - GEORGE 20
```

I does that because it groups rows by whole hour and it merges it to the first row based on the timestamp not on the last one.. If I would change DAY_HOUR to DAY MINUTE that would theoreticaly solve the problem, but I want to have longer timespan.

Does anyone also know a simple solution how to group rows by miliseconds?

Thanks!

Comment: General GROUP BY tip: "If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." I know MySQL is a bit "flexible" when it comes to GROUP BY, but if you follow that tip you'll never go wrong!